# MVC 4 UrlAction remove default controller from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Im sure this is a simple question, but cant seem to find a solutions. Basically, we are using MVC 4, and have a logo which links to the home page,  which is done the following way (standard stuff):-

```
@Html.ActionLink("MySite", "home")
```

however, this produces the link

http://www.mysite.co.uk/home/index

we need it to produce the link

http://www.mysite.co.uk

ie. without the controler or action.

We have tried,

```
  @Html.ActionLink("MySite", "")
```

however, this still adds in /home/index

---

As requested, route:-

```
     routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{param}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, param = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Can you post your route configuration?

Comment: @Marko Route info added to above, thanks

Comment: The second parameter is the action name. Try `@Html.ActionLink("MySite", "Index", "Home")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke hi, i think you may have miss understood the question. this will still produce the url "http://www.mysite.co.uk/index/home"

We simply just want it to produce the url http://www.mysite.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: It works fine for me. Is this your only route? (and I assume `@Html.ActionLink("MySite", "home")` is a typo then)

Comment: @StephenMuecke when you click on the link generated by 
@Html.ActionLink("MySite", "Index", "Home")
what link is displayed in the browser for you?
MySite/home/index ?

Comment: Just `localhost:50260/`

Comment: @StephenMuecke strange,  we are getting /home/index

is there any setting that we are missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have no other routes defined, and that this route is in the `RouteConfig.cs` file